# angular format 2 digits ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie on angularJS.

I want to divide 2 numbers, but I want to **round the result with two digits**.

I try many things :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="var3" ng-value="var3 = Math.round((var1/var2)*100)/100" />

<input type="number" ng-model="var3" ng-value="var3 = (var1/var2).toFixed(2)" />
```

Do you have any ideas ?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwqycgpk/)

Comment: if `var3` is always equal to `var1/var2` why do you want to have input for it? just display it as text

Comment: I display it because the user want to see the value before submitting form.

Comment: Your `toFixed()` example would work with 1 minor change, Angular returns a string, change the input type to text. I would also suggest changing the input to disabled that way the user knows it will be submitted but they aren't allowed to change the value.

Comment: That's awesome Asok. Very big thanks, I can keep my ng-model and ng-value. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it with `ng-model` and `ng-value` but this filter works fine:

```
<input type="number" value="{{ var3=var1/var2 | number:2 }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I don't know why it does'nt work with ng-value or ng-model. I will manage with you answer to do that I want. Thanks !